# returning an uint array + gas + cost efficient problem?

Tags: solidity, gas, arrays

I have a growing public array

```
struct MatchInfo {
    uint256 matchId;  
    bool isMatchDone; 
}

MatchInfo[] public matchInfo;
```

and I want to return an array of `uint256` which will loop through `matchInfo` and find where `isMatchdone == false`

```
function getUnfinishedMatches() public constant returns (uint256[]) {
  uint256[] memory unFinishedMatches = new uint[](getMatchCount());

  for (uint i = 0; i <= matchInfo.length; i++) {
    if (matchInfo.isMatchdone == false) {
      unFinishedMatches[i] = matchInfo.matchId;
    }
  }

  return unFinishedMatches;
}
```

I saw somewhere in the post that `constant returns` will not use up gas. Is it true? if it is not true, is the above function a bad way of approach/practice to return an array in solidity? If so, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends. There are two ways of calling functions from a smart contract

1. Call them from an Ethereum transaction. This will call the function on-chain and cost you gas from the execution.
2. Call them **read-only** without creating a transaction. This costs no gas. This can be done because, since it's a *constant* function and doesn't modify the state, it can be called without creating an on-chain transaction. This wont work for functions that modify the state because the state wont persist since there is no transaction. This is usually done in web3 by doing `call()` on the function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if there is `constant` modifier, it would not cost any gas because it does not create a transaction. I see. If I take out `constant` like `function sellProduct(string _name, string _description, uint256 _price) public {}` then it would create transaction and cost gas right?

Comment: Correct. Note that you *can* still create a transaction to a constant function if you aren't doing it correctly in Web3. A function named `sellProduct` probably wouldn't make sense to be constant as the name makes it sound like it would need to modify the state and thus not be constant.

Comment: I see. so I still need to use constant correctly. Thanks.